# carouFredSel Slider - prevent scroll to top on slides rolling

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, jquery-plugins, caroufredsel

I'm trying to figure out the solution for this issue. Whenever the carousel slides moves or slides on rolling, page scroll to top of the screen.

Reference Site:
http://www.resmed.com/uk/en/index.html

How to replicate: scroll down to half of the banner slider and make sure carousel slide banner is visible to you

Comment: You need to provide code that you have tried. We can't help you with just a reference site.

Comment: Hi Ravi patel, Since i'm new to this blog not able to add the 500 lines of code.

Comment: JSFIDDLE link: https://jsfiddle.net/prabhumachismo/4aqk4gtz/1/#&togetherjs=xQCTghg6f6

Comment: Oddly we are having the exact same issue in a production site. We are using version 6.2.1. of carouFredSel.

Comment: Looks like it was a change in Chrome. We cannot reproduce in other browsers and other evidence suggests it's chrome. Setting fade off resolves the problem for us.

Comment: Hi tidmutt, Could you please explain in detail. i got frustrated for the last 3 days not able to resolve it, so please let me know solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Tidmutt, waiting for your positive resposne.

Comment: Handy Andy Mutter solved it. @Prabhu Shanmugam, you should mark his answer as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been searching for the same answer for a while as well. It seems to be a bug introduced in Chrome 57 for fade effects on the caroufredsel.js.

I am not 100% why this works but I have managed to get a fix anyway.

I have basically created a div inside the carousel wrapper which overlays the whole slideshow. This then stops it from jumping to the top of the screen again.

Hope this solves your problem. :)

```css
.chrome-fix {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
            <div class="caroufredsel_wrapper">
                <div class="chrome-fix"></div>
                <ul id="foo2">
                    <li>
                        <img src="/img.jpg" alt="" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="/img2.jpg" alt="" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="/img3.jpg" alt="" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="/img4.jpg" alt="" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer / hack as this works. Great job!

Comment: Been trouble-shooting this issue for a couple of hours now, this just saved me a couple of more hours of trouble-shooting.  Works great, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Example solution (#featured_slider - slider id):

```
#featured_slider:before {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. And doesn't require any changes to the html.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this issue by adding the CSS *overflow-anchor: none;* to the *.slider-item* element

I think it has something to do with how later versions of Chrome handle scroll position when HTML content changes.

Answer (score 0):

Change the transition type (scroll fx) to something different
My scroll settings which doesn't cause the page to scroll to top (before the fx property was set to 'crossfade'):

scroll: { duration: 600, timeoutDuration: 8000, fx: 'cover' },

The fx property can have these values (I haven't tested them all, you have to test to see which of them works and which of the working ones you prefer): 
"none", "scroll", "directscroll", "fade", "crossfade", "cover", "cover-fade", "uncover" or "uncover-fade"

Comment: Hi Buddy, Thanks for sharing your comments, i have already tried with all scroll options but still getting this scroll to top issue for fade effects, rest of the options are works fine.